# Folder/ Directory delete with progress

Tags: python, python-2.7, directory, progress

I am writing an application using pyqt. There is a requirement to delete a folder which contain sub folders and many files. The path to folder is residing in usb disk. While the deletion is going on, I would like to show the users with updated progress bar. Here is the sample code I tried to calculate percentage while deletion is going on.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import subprocess
import os

def progress_uninstall_dir():
    uninstall_path = "path/to/folder"
    usb_mount = "path/to/usb/mount"
    if not os.path.exists(uninstall_path):
        print ("Directory not found.")
    else:
        proc=subprocess.Popen("du -ck " + usb_mount + " | grep total | cut -f 1", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, )
        inintial_usb_size = int(proc.communicate()[0])
        proc=subprocess.Popen("du -ck " + uninstall_path + " | grep total | cut -f 1", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, )
        folder_size_to_remove = int(proc.communicate()[0])
        delete_process = subprocess.Popen('rm -rf ' + uninstall_path,  shell=True)
        while delete_process.poll() is None:
            proc=subprocess.Popen("du -ck " + usb_mount + " | grep total | cut -f 1", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, )
            current_size =   int(proc.communicate()[0])
            diff_size = int(inintial_usb_size - current_size)
            percentage = float(diff_size/folder_size_to_remove)*100
            print (percentage)


progress_uninstall_dir()
```

However, the above code always give `0` as percentage. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem might be due to integer division when calculating `percentage`.  The code you have right now divides one integer by another (presumably obtaining the value 0) and then converts the result to a float.  You'd be better served by converting one of the two integers to float before the division:

```
percentage = float(diff_size)/folder_size_to_remove*100
```